# How can I set coordinates to display a specific part of my screen as the center - pygame

Tags: python, pygame, display, centering

I am making a game it is a 2d tile map with scrolling and four direction movements.
I want to set the center a specific part of the map that does not display as center I would have to move to that part of the map for it to center I want to start off at that point as the center.

Comment: move player coordinates to that point? what? can You explain a bit better what You want to achieve, maybe provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have `N`x`M` square tiles with size `tile_size` and the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object associated with the window (`screen`).
Set up a rectangle ([`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)) size of the map and align the center of this rectangle with the center of the screen:

```py
map_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, N * tile_size, M * tile_size)
map_rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
```

At the top left of the `map_rect` rectangle is the offset with which you can place the tiles:

```py
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M)
        x = i * tile_size
        y = j * tile_size

        # place tile at (x, y)
        # [...]
```

The same using [`range(start, stop, step)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```py
for x in range(map_rect.left, map_rect.right, tile_size):
    for y in range(map_rect.top, map_rect.bottom, tile_size):

        # place tile at (x, y)
        # [...]
```